# 3D procedural mesh generation: How do I properly split a tree branch into 2?

Tags: 3d, geometry, computational-geometry, cgal, procedural-generation

Im trying to procedurally generate a tree by recursively running a branch generating function.
The vertices are created floor by floor. When a split occurs I want to create 2 new floors with adjusted size and direction. How do I properly connect the vertices of the old polygon with the 2 new polygons?

[Current model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FJ7y.png)

Right now Im connecting the vertices of the top floor of the current branch with the new vertex polygon that has the a greater radius. The second, smaller branch is not connected at all with the main mesh. This leads to mostly smaller inconveniences besides one point:
In the end a mesh smoothener adjusts the vertex positions. Because its not a single big mesh and the vertices of the second split branch are not connected witht he main branch, the smoothener does not work correct.

[Connection issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8mrN.png)

So i want to find a solution to build one connected mesh when the split occurs.
I have a badly drawn example trying to show how the split should occur.
Basically connect the vertices of the main branch polygon with the 2 split branch polygons.
More vertices can be added as well.

[How to split example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqAIt.jpg)

Comment: Tree generators like the default Unity one cheat by sinking the base of the second level branches into the mesh of the first level. If you insist on doing it "properly" you could look up code/mesh layouts for pipe t-joints and pipe y-joints, but that would be your homework, since it's quite a chunk of work to code.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Thats what i kind of did as well, but it lead to the problem i described. Will look up pipe t- and j-joints.